# AS3 TextField.textWidth ignore whitespace at end

Tags: whitespace, textfield, actionscript-2

I'm trying to calculate the textWidth, but it seems to ignore the white spaces at the end. The text

"Hello" 
"Hello "

returns the same text width. A string with " " returns 0. How do I calculate the width with the space?

Answer (score 0):

You could always get the length of the string.

```
text.length
```

And then multiply that by how wide your characters are.

For example:

```
var aChar:String = "A";
var textWidth:int = (text.length) * (width of aChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose a terminator character, for Example "|".
2. Calculate Width(Text+Termainator)-Width(Terminator).